# How to check audio quality after changing import settings

Tags: unity

I have changed the quality of an audio clip from 100 to 10 in the import settings. But when I played the clip from the inspector, I didn't hear any noticeable difference

The compression format of the audio clip is set to 'Vorbis'

So I wonder if it's the original file or the compressed file that is being played by the Unity Editor?

Comment: Have you tried importing two copies of the sound at different quality settings, then playing them both in a build to compare them? You may have simply chosen a sound that compresses very well.

Comment: Yes. I duplicated the clip and compare them with quality set to 1 and 100. Still no difference. May be we can't test audio quality within the editor.

Comment: Remember I said "in a build" — that's how you'll determine whether the editor is hiding something from.you, or if the sound really does sound the same after more aggressive compression.

Comment: Okay, I understand.